# Google Maps Api Fusion Table select geometry where name equals variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Basically I want to pass the inputValue variable into the fusion table query to find the geometry where the value of column 'Name' equals inputValue.

I just need to know how this should be written. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code Below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//   function init() {

var baseLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.7713,-1.5550);
var newLatLng;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: baseLatLng
});

var searchOptions = {
    center: baseLatLng,
    mapTypeID: 'roadmap',
    componentRestrictions: {country: "uk"}
};

var input = document.getElementById('search');

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, searchOptions);

var inputValue = document.getElementById('search').value;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

$("#go").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    geocodeAddress(geocoder);
    layer.setMap(map);

});


function geocodeAddress(geocoder) {
    var address = document.getElementById('search').value;
    geocoder.geocode({address: address, region: 'uk'}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
        newLatLng = latitude + ',' + longitude;
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "latitude:" + latitude + "<br>" + "longitude:" + longitude;

    });
}

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'Geometry',
        from: 'xxxx',
        where: "'Name' = inputValue" ---HERE!
    },
    styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.3
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Thanks,
Ollie

Comment: Your "Name" column is of type number.

Comment: I can select a boundary like this: where: "'Name' = 'Derbyshire'" but I want to replace the county with the search variable

Comment: The search variable isn't going to match the names in the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. I'll leave this here for anyone in the future.

```
function getBoundry() {
        var address = document.getElementById('search').value;
        var query = "\"\'Name\' =  " + "\'" + address + "\'" + '\"'; 

        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'Geometry',
                from: 'xxxxx',
                where: query
            },
            styles: [{
                polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor: '#00FF00',
                    fillOpacity: 0.3
                }

            }]

        });
        layer.setMap(map);
    }
```

Then the funciton is called in the click event.

```
$("#go").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        getBoundry();

    });
```